# How to inform client-side that webhook event handler finished?

Tags: .net, jwt, stripe-payments, webhooks, maui

I am trying to integrate Stripe online one-time payments into my .NET MAUI mobile app. The payment is for a Premium membership. After the user finishes the payment I redirect him to a success page and on the server-side I have a webhook that listens for checkout.session.completed event to update the user in my database to have the Premium account turned on. I am using JWT tokens to authenticate the user and store user role (Premium or basic). The problem is I generate this JWT token on log-in and I need to regenerate a new token when a user makes a payment for the token to have the Premium role in it. So after the client-side gets redirected to success page by Stripe checkout I need the client-side to get the new JWT token but calling the server before the webhook has been processed could lead to the client not getting the Premium. How could I handle this problem?

I was thinking of polling the server in the success page until the webhook completes but that doesn't seem like a good practice.

Comment: webhook methods for payment awaits is an obsolete practice and could reach a lot of functional errors

Answer (score 0):

Regenerating the token from webhook is the best approach and [the recommended implementation by Stripe so far](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill). Relying on the success page could lead to scenarios such as your customer accidentally closed their browser, lost internet access (imagine they were on a train went into a tunnel) when you will lost track of your transaction.

If you need to pick up some information when handling the webhook event, use [Metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata).